# How do I avoid timezone adjustment issues on Spring JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, date, jpa

I am developing a Spring JPA web app on OSX which is currently using MariaDB hosted on my local machine. A query of my timezone settings on MariaDB shows the following:

```
    MariaDB [testdb]> show variables like '%time_zone%';
+------------------+--------+
| Variable_name    | Value  |
+------------------+--------+
| system_time_zone | EST    |
| time_zone        | SYSTEM |
+------------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [testdb]>
```

I have a @Query which uses a date. The table being queried has a field defined as date. If I turn on trace-level logging I see that the date is properly passed but has been adjusted down by 1 day by the time the select statement is assembled. This obviously causes the query to return incorrect results. If I run the query manually, it obviously fails to return the desired row. If I run the query manually with the unadjusted date, the proper row is returned.

```
2016-11-25 12:11:46 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [3] as [DATE] - [2016-11-04]
2016-11-25 12:29:00 TRACE org.hibernate.loader.Loader:1934 - Bound [4] parameters total
2016-11-25 12:29:00 TRACE org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl:437 - Registering result set [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl@d38f349]
2016-11-25 12:29:00 TRACE org.hibernate.loader.Loader:946 - Processing result set
2016-11-25 12:29:00 TRACE org.hibernate.loader.Loader:970 - Done processing result set (0 rows)
2016-11-25 12:29:00 TRACE org.hibernate.loader.Loader:1112 - Total objects hydrated: 0
2016-11-25 12:29:00 TRACE org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl:412 - Releasing statement [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement@bf12e91: select vacationda0_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE1_3_, vacationda0_.TYPE as TYPE2_3_, vacationda0_.VACATION_DAY as VACATION3_3_ from VACATION_DAY vacationda0_ where (vacationda0_.EMPLOYEE_ID, vacationda0_.TYPE)=('000448719', 'personal') and vacationda0_.VACATION_DAY='2016-11-03']
```

With tracing, I can see that the problem occurs when the the date is formatted for the EST timezone. I would think that if the database is running the same TimeZone as the app, then the date shouldn't be adjusted. Obviously this isn't the case.

Can someone suggest a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Always use and serialize times in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because when you call it by application, it uses the default of system (sync time if it is AWS or other cloud using NTP time server). So from application specify the time zone then your problem will be resolved.

Also, in java 8, timezone is

```
LocalDateTime date = Instant
                            .ofEpochMilli(new Date().getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                            .toLocalDateTime();
```

Comment: Not sure if this applies as the time supplied to the query is a java.sql.Date which has no time component. Unfortunately, it does have a timezone. Seems that presents an inconsistency.

Comment: Well, apparently java.sql.date does contain a time component even though you can't retrieve it. I have checked two java.sql.Date variables, both containing showing the same date in the variables window while debugging under eclips. However, their fastTime components which are used in comparisons differ by 3,600,000 which is one hour. When you compare them by year, month and day they are equal.